# HTACCESS if COOKIE set REWRITE spezific URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies, url-rewriting, redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
```

if this cookie ist set with parameter "mobile"

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} fdx_switcher=mobile [NC]
```

check if Url = (...)/jetztspielen

```
RewriteCond /jetztspielen(.*)$ [NC,L]
```

change "/jetztspielen" to mobile_login with parameters

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /mobile_login%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Doesn't work :( please Help

:)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} fdx_switcher=mobile [NC]
RewriteCond /jetztspielen(.*)$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /mobile_login%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` directive is missing the `%{REQUEST_URI}` parameter as `TestString`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} fdx_switcher=mobile [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /jetztspielen(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /mobile_login%1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: @ChristianTheiß You can select the reply as answer if it helped. The question will not appear under unanswered questions list then.